# How can I use a method of the defined type of the generic class?

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Team<AbstractMember> {

    public int getPoints() {
        int points = 0;
        for (AbstractMember member : memberList) {
            points += member.**getPoints()**;
        }
        return points;
    }
}
```

I want to go over the points of the members and return them, but the fact, that AbstractMember is the type of the generic class disables the method `member.getPoints()`.
Eclipse says `The method getPoints() is undefined for the type AbstractMember`.

```
public abstract class AbstractMember{
    private String name;
    private int points;

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}
```

How can I use a method of the defined type of the generic class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this declaration

```
public class Team<AbstractMember>
```

to

```
public class Team<T extends AbstractMember>
```

Then, in your code you should use `T` to refer to the class Type. For example, you will have to change the `for` loop you from

```
for (AbstractMember member : memberList)
```

to

```
for (T member : memberList) {
```

Comment: This `T extends MYCLASS` was needed in like every generic class i made. But why does it only work in this way??

Comment: You could have saved lot of time by doing `public class ATeam extends Team<AbstractMember>`. Note that the class will extend directly from `Team<AbstractMember>` and no need to use `T` inside it, instead all generic elements/methods would use `AbstractMember`.